# Is this space normal?

Tags: general-topology

The space is this:

> Let $D=\{0,1\}$, and let $Y=D^\mathfrak{c}$. For $y\in Y\;$ let $\operatorname{supp}(y)=\{\xi<\mathfrak{c}:y(\xi)=1\}$, the *support* of $y$, and let $X=\{x\in Y:0<|\operatorname{supp}(x)|\le\omega_1\}$.

PS: We know $\Sigma$-product of metric spaces is normal, see [here](http://bing.proxysec.com/baidu.com.php?u=143f0f9cd7eaf5e0f2Oi8vZGFudG9wb2xvZ3kud29yZHByZXNzLmNvbS8yMDA5LzEyLzEyL2Etbm90ZS1hYm91dC1zaWdtYS1wcm9kdWN0LW9mLWNvbXBhY3Qtc3BhY2VzLw==&b=3&f=norefer).

The question is: is this space normal?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is not normal.

Basic open sets in $X$ are of the form

$$B(F_0,F_1)=\{x\in X:x(\xi)=0\text{ for }\xi\in F_0\text{ and }x(\xi)=1\text{ for }\xi\in F_1\}\;,$$

where $F_0$ and $F_1$ are disjoint finite sets of indices; let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of such basic open sets.

Assume first that $2^\omega=\omega_1$, i.e., that CH holds. Let the index set for the product $D^\mathfrak{c}$ be $\omega_1\cdot2$. For $\alpha\le\omega_1$ and $\beta<\omega_1$ define the point $x_{\alpha,\beta}\in X$ as follows:

$$x_{\alpha,\beta}(\xi)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }\xi<\alpha\text{ or }\omega_1\le\xi<\omega_1+\beta\\
1,&\text{if }\alpha\le\xi<\omega_1\text{ or }\xi\ge\omega_1+\beta\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $Z$ be the set of such points $x_{\alpha,\beta}$. If $x\in X\setminus Z$, then either there are $\alpha<\beta<\omega_1$ such that $x(\alpha)=1$ and $x(\beta)=0$, or there are $\alpha<\beta$ such that $\omega_1\le\alpha$, $x(\alpha)=1$, and $x(\beta)=0$; in either case $B\big(\{\beta\},\{\alpha\}\big)$ is a nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $Z$, so $Z$ is closed in $X$.

Let $H=\{x_{\alpha,\alpha}:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ and $K=\{x_{\omega_1,\alpha}:\alpha<\omega_1\}$; clearly $H$ and $K$ are disjoint, and I claim that they are closed in $Z$ (and hence in $X$).

> If $x\in X\setminus H$, at least one of the following must be the case:
>
> 1. there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $x(\alpha)=0$ and $x(\omega_1+\alpha)=1$;
> 2. there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $x(\alpha)=1$ and $x(\omega_1+\alpha)=0$;
>
> In case (1) $B\big(\{\alpha\},\{\omega_1+\alpha\}\big)$ is a nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $H$; in case (2), $B\big(\{\omega_1+\alpha\},\{\alpha\}\big)$ is.
>
> If $x\in Z\setminus K$, there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $x(\alpha)=1$, in which case $B\big(\varnothing,\{\alpha\}\big)$ is a nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $K$.

Now suppose that $H\subseteq U$ and $K\subseteq V$, where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets in $X$. For each $x_{\alpha,\alpha}\in H$ there is a $B(F_\alpha,G_\alpha)\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x_{\alpha,\alpha}\in B(F_\alpha,G_\alpha)\subseteq U$. Now

$$x_{\alpha,\alpha}(\xi)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }\xi<\alpha\\
1,&\text{if }\alpha\le\xi<\omega_1\\
0,&\text{if }\omega_1\le\xi<\omega_1+\alpha\\
1,&\text{if }\xi\ge\omega_1+\alpha\;,
\end{cases}$$

so without loss of generality we may assume that $\alpha,\omega_1+\alpha\in G_\alpha$. For $\alpha\ne 0$ we may further assume that $F_\alpha\cap\alpha\ne\varnothing\ne F_\alpha\setminus\omega_1$, and if $\mu_\alpha=\max(F_\alpha\cap\alpha)$, then $\max(F_\alpha\setminus\omega_1)=\omega_1+\mu_\alpha$. It follows that

$$Z\cap B(F_\alpha,G_\alpha)=\{x_{\beta,\gamma}\in Z:\eta_\alpha<\beta,\gamma\le\alpha\}\;.$$

By the [pressing-down lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma) there are an $\eta<\omega_1$ and a cofinal subset $S$ of $\omega_1$ such that $\eta_\alpha=\eta$ for each $\alpha\in S$. But then

$$U\supseteq Z\cap\bigcup_{\alpha\in S}B(F_\alpha,G_\alpha)=\{x_{\beta,\gamma}\in Z:\eta<\beta,\gamma<\omega_1\}\;,$$

and it’s easy to see that if $\eta<\alpha<\omega_1$, then $x_{\omega_1,\alpha}\in K\cap\operatorname{cl}U=\varnothing$, an obvious contradiction. It follows that $H$ and $K$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets and hence that $X$ is not normal.

> This is essentially just the argument that $(\omega_1+1)\times\omega_1$ isn’t normal, because $\{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ and $\{\omega_1\}\times\omega_1$ can’t be separated by disjoint open sets. It works because there is no point $x_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$: it would have empty support.

If $2^\omega>\omega_1$, only minor changes are necessary. First, we use $2^\omega$ as the index set for the product $D^\mathfrak{c}$. Then we define $x_{\alpha,\beta}$ by

$$x_{\alpha,\beta}(\xi)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }\xi<\alpha\omega_1\le\xi<\omega_1+\beta\\
1,&\text{if }\alpha\le\xi<\omega_1\\
0,&\text{if }\omega_1\le\xi<\omega_1+\beta\\
1,&\text{if }\omega_1+\beta\le\xi<\omega_1\cdot2\\
0,&\text{if }\xi\ge\omega_1\cdot2\;.
\end{cases}$$

$Z,H$, and $K$ are as before; the only change is that a point of $x\in X$ might fail to be in $Z$ because $x(\xi)=1$ for some $\xi\ge\omega_1\cdot2$, in which case $B\big(\varnothing,\{\xi\}\big)$ is a nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $Z$.

Comment: @Brain M Scott can u prove that (w1+1)x w1 is not normal

Comment: @math: Let $\Delta=\{\langle\xi,\xi\rangle:\xi<\omega_1\}$. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $\Delta$, then for each $\xi<\omega_1$ there is an $\eta_\xi<\xi$ such that $(\eta_\xi,\xi]\times(\eta_\xi,\xi]\subseteq U$. By the [pressing-down lemma](http://david.efnet-math.org/?p=4) there are $A\subseteq\omega_1$ and $\eta<\omega_1$ such that $|A|=\omega_1$ and $\eta_xi=\eta$ for each $\xi\in A$. It follows that $U\supseteq(\eta,\omega_1)\times(\eta,\omega_1)$. Thus, for any $\alpha\in(\eta,\omega_1)$ every open nbhd of $\langle\omega_1,\alpha\rangle$ meets $U$. This shows that the closed sets ...

Comment: ... $\Delta$ and $\{\omega_1\}\times\omega_1$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

Comment: @Brain M Scott do u mean Δ={⟨ξ,ξ⟩:ξ<ω 1 } is closed set

Comment: @Brain M Scott I mean is granted or we have to prove it

Comment: @math: Yes, $\Delta$ is a closed set in $(\omega_1+1)\times\omega_1$. This follows from the fact $\omega_1+1$ and $\omega_1$ are Hausdorff. At some point it has to be proved, but it’s a very easy argument.

Comment: @Brain M Scott thank u very much it clears

Comment: @math: You’re welcome; I’d glad that it’s straightened out now.

Comment: @Brain M Scott I have one question regard this proof can we proof or disproof that every subspace of T4 is T4

Comment: @math: No, because it’s not true. For example, $(\omega_1+1)\times(\omega_1+1)$ is compact and Hausdorff, so it’s $T_4$, but its subspace $(\omega_1+1)\times\omega_1$ is not $T_4$.

Comment: @Brain M Scott could u give me another example I know this we discussed on this types of space before

Comment: @math: That’s about the simplest example that I know. However, you can make lots of examples in the following way. Let $X$ be any Tikhonov space that isn’t normal (e.g., the [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane)).  Every Tikhonov space [is a subspace of $[0,1]^I$ for some index set $I$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space#Embeddings). By the Tikhonov product theorem $[0,1]^I$ is compact and Hausdorff and therefore $T_4$, while $X$ is not.